# UnknownHostException while connecting to Azure Cosmos DB from Java code

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've created a simple `Java` project. And added the `JARs` to the `classpath`. In the file **BulkImport.java**, I'm trying to connect to the `Azure Cosmos DB`. However, I'm running into the following error.

> Warning : [main] WARN
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.GlobalEndpointManager - Failed to
>   retrieve database account information.
>   com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClientException:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: This is usually a temporary error
>   during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not
>   receive a response from an authoritative server.

**BulkImport.java**

```
public class BulkImport {

    //public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BulkImport.class);
    public static final String ENDPOINT = "https://<xxxx>.documents.azure.com:443/";
    public static final String PRIMARY_KEY = xxxx
    public static final String DATABASE = "xxxx"
    public static final String CONTAINER = "xxxx";
    public static final String PARTITION_KEY = "/id";
    public static final int THROUGHPUT = 10000;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        executeBulkImport();
        System.out.print("Done");
    }

    public static void executeBulkImport() throws Exception
    {
        ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy();
        connectionPolicy.setMaxPoolSize(1000);

        // Below line is giving the error
        DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(ENDPOINT, PRIMARY_KEY, connectionPolicy, ConsistencyLevel.Session);  

        DocumentCollection collection = Utilities.createEmptyCollectionIfNotExists(client, DATABASE, CONTAINER, PARTITION_KEY, THROUGHPUT);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\samplejson.json")) {

            Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);

            JSONArray jsonArray  = (JSONArray) obj;
            System.out.println(jsonArray);
            if (jsonArray  != null) {
                int len = jsonArray.size();
                for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
                    list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
            System.out.println(list.get(0));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds(30);
        client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests(9);

       // Builder pattern
        DocumentBulkExecutor.Builder bulkExecutorBuilder = DocumentBulkExecutor.builder().from(client, DATABASE, CONTAINER,
                collection.getPartitionKey(), 20000);
        try {
            DocumentBulkExecutor bulkExecutor = bulkExecutorBuilder.build();
            client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds(0);
            client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests(0);
            BulkImportResponse bulkImportResponse = bulkExecutor.importAll(list, false, false, null);
            System.out.println(bulkImportResponse.getNumberOfDocumentsImported());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Please help me understand the issue.

Comment: Apparently Java can't resolve the host name. Have you tried other ways? Like `dig <xxxx>.documents.azure.com`?
Is there maybe a proxy you have to go through? Quite often the case in corporate environments.

Comment: How can I use dig? Also, yes I thought about proxy. But I tried with/without proxy, it's giving the same result.

Comment: `dig <the address you'd like to connect to>`. Just google it. https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/dns/use-dig-to-perform-manual-dns-queries/

Comment: Check if you can resolve the address you're connecting to manually.

Comment: I'm on windows so I did `nslookup`. It is returning back the IP Address!

Comment: It returned the IP but then it said DNS timed out

Comment: I've raised my issue here : https://github.com/aarohi-001/BulkImportCosmos/issues/1#issue-536272671

Comment: @lexicore, When I passed the IP Address directly instead of the endpoint, the error changed to **"org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException"**. Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem because I was trying to connect from an on-prem environment. Setting proxy helped:

```
 ConnectionPolicy defaultPolicy = ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault();
 HttpHost proxy = HttpHost.create("your-proxy-host:8080");
 defaultPolicy.setProxy(proxy);
 defaultPolicy.setConnectionMode(ConnectionMode.Gateway);
```

This code works with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-documentdb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

If you have other version of azure-java-sdk you need to find similar solution to set your proxy.

Comment: As of now I just changed the environment. I was trying from a virtual machine and also the version of the eclipse was Neon whereas I switched to other version. However this could be of help if I switch back to the previous environment. Will check, thanks!